# Install python package through dockerfile - Dependency Error

Tags: python, docker, installation, jupyter-notebook, containers

I Have a docker file that pulls the Jupiter's minimal image and installs a python package named preprocess1.

Here is the docker file code:

```
# import pre-built image from minimal notebook 
FROM jupyter/minimal-notebook
# Install required libraries
RUN pip install preprocess1
```

After building and running the image:

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 notebook_demo
```

I open up the jupyter note book and try to import the
preprocess1 library. That results in error

```
from preprocess1 import toolkit as tk
```

This throws an error as pandas & ipywidgets are not installed on the minimal image.

I have already tried adding a requirment.txt file with preprocess1 in it but it still does not pick up preprocess1's dependencies

Usually when we do pip install a package it also installs all of its dependencies
so how do I accomplish the same thing in this container ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a requirements.txt file with your packages:

```
   pandas
   ipywidgets
   preprocess1
```

And in your dockerfile :

```
ADD             ./requirements.txt ./
RUN             python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: I have already tried adding it through requirement.txt file, it still does not work . I will add this to my question. Do i need to add preprocess1's dependencies into the requirement file as well ?

Comment: You should try that

Comment: well that defies the purpose , since I have to manually write all the dependencies in the requirement file , it should install them when i pip install preprocess1

Comment: Are the dependencies included in the setup.py of the preprocess1 module?